# Find out which field a file is being uploaded to

Tags: django

```py
def _image_directory_path(instance, filename):
    pass
    
class TreatyParagraph(CommentMixin, models.Model):    
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)    
    english = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")
    english_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=False, default="", upload_to=_image_directory_path)
    spanish = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default="")
    spanish_img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=False, default="", upload_to=_image_directory_path)
```

I want to organize file storage like this:

```
253e8498-7859-4490-b8ff-644f928607e5
    en.png
    sp.png
```

Depending on the field I'd like to rename the file (english_img corresponds to en.png etc.).

The problem is that I have failed to find out which field a file belongs to.

[image]

If only I could determine which field a file is being uploaded to, I'd just sliced the first two letters.

Comment: Is there still a chance to change the DB structure? If so, I'd recommend to create a new separate model for each language variant instead of having it all in the same table. Otherwise it's not very clear what data are you getting in the request. All data, even the data which already exist in DB? Then compare all the data in DB vs. in incoming request. If some data are not the same, then there is your answer. Or are you getting only new data? Then there is your answer already.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko , thank you. If you organize this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.